# JS on checkbox Change enable or disable a radio button

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, event-handling, radio-button

I have a check box that I want to enable these radio buttons. what I have does not work. how can I JS that?

im new. :(

```
var sipch = document.querySelector("input[name=sip]");
sipch.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if(sipch.checked) {
        document.getElementById("protocol").disabled=false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("protocol").disabled=true;
    }
});
```

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sip" onsubmit="goPFive(event)" method="get">do this?
<input type="radio" class="testD" name="protocol" value="udp" disabled checked/>UDP
<input type="radio" class="testD" name="protocol" value="tcp" disabled />TCP
```

Answer (score 0):

group your radio input with [fieldset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) then set disabled attribute at fieldset element

```html
<fieldset id="radioWrapper" disabled>
  <input type="radio" name="protocol" class="testD" value="udp"/>UDP
  <input type="radio" name="protocol" class="testD" value="tcp" />TCP
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).